# How can I pass a variable for an object containing many keys and values in Flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I'm new to Facebook Flow.

https://github.com/facebook/flow

Currently, I have a class something like this and I don't like what I have in the argument of the constructor method is long.

```
class SamplePerson {

    constructor(obj: {id: string, name: string, age: number, height: number, birthdate: string, sex: string, weight: number}') {
        this._id = obj.id;
        this._name = obj.name;
        this._age = obj.age;
        this._height = obj.height;
        this._weight = obj.weight;
        this._birthdate = obj.birthdate;
        this._sex = obj.sex;
    }

}
```

So, rather than something like the above, I want it to be something like this on the below.

What is the appropriate way to pass a variable containing type information to the constructor's argument?

## Something like this

```
const objType = {id: string, name: string, age: number, height: number, birthdate: string, sex: string, weight: number};

class SamplePerson {

    constructor(obj: objType) {
        this._id = obj.id;
        this._name = obj.name;
        this._age = obj.age;
        this._height = obj.height;
        this._weight = obj.weight;
        this._birthdate = obj.birthdate;
        this._sex = obj.sex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not aware about "Flow-typed", but how are you creating an object of "SamplePerson" in the first example?

Comment: I mean Flow. new SamplePerson({id: '', name:'', etc})

Comment: Not sure if you can simply do "obj: Object" in your constructor

Comment: obj: Object would be valid, but then you lose info about which specific fields are present or not. It's better to explicitly specify the expected fields when possible using a type alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use type instead of const when declaring ObjType. You can read about flow type aliases (in this case, ObjType is a type alias) here https://flow.org/en/docs/types/aliases/

```
type ObjType = {id: string, name: string, age: number, height: number, birthdate: string, sex: string, weight: number};

class SamplePerson {
    constructor(obj: ObjType) {
        ...
    }
}
```